# Thevenin Termination Current Calculation and Iol/Ioh

Tags: current, termination

I am calculating the current draw for a thevenin termination and am having issues with the Iol and Ioh from the datasheet.

[image]

From my understanding, when the source goes high (Voh), then Vtt (dest input node) will go to Voh (ideally, Vdd). The current is then Vdd / R2 and current flows through the source and into ground. There is no contribution from R1 branch since Vtt and Vdd are equal and there is not voltage drop.

If Vdd = 1.8, then the current I calculate is 18 mA (1.8V/100ohm), but the datasheet below for HSTL I 1.8V has -8 mA for Ioh. Aside from the wrong direction, it seems as though it would not be able to push out 18 mA in any case.

Vcco = 1.8V and Vref = 0.9V. 50 ohm represents a 50 ohm impedance transmission line.

[image]

[Source](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds202.pdf) page 7

Can someone help explain what I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Advice: link to the data sheet.

Comment: It can supply +/- 8 mA so that means you won't get full rail voltage p-p at the input with the values of R1 and R2 you have chosen. Is this a problem?

Comment: To really figure this out, you need to know the input impedance of the destination driver.

Comment: Is the 50 ohm block at the output of the source representing a transmission line?

Comment: If it falls within the range of Vih and Vil then it would not necessarily be a problem. The Vih and Vil of the receiving device is the same as on the table. If it was only 8 mA, then Vtt would be 0.8V which would not satisfy Vih which would be a problem. Are you implying the math I used originally in the post is correct? 

@PeterSmith Yes it is

Comment: What is the value of \$V_{CCO}\$? What is the value of \$V_{REF}\$? It would help if you labeled all of the voltages in the schematic and used names that were consistent with your equations and the datasheet.

Comment: @laptop2d Unfortunately, I do not have that data. How would you solve this if you did have it?

Comment: @Engineer For starters, you need to say something about the dest impedance, is it high enough to be neglected (like above 100kΩ?) or is the input current in the mA range.